# post on facebook wall through php application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I am going to develop a site where I want to subscribe users from facebook.
If the user subscribe successfully then application will post on his wall when something new happen in our site.

can anybody help me about this.
Thank you in advance

Comment: any body know it ??? pls tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to request "publish_stream" permissions from the user. Read the information about 'publishing' in [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).
The call will look something like this (using the facebook sdk) :

```
$facebook->api('/'.$user_id.'/feed','post',$post_details);
```

where $post_details is an array containing pictures, descriptions, links... etc..
Read from the link - it is all explained there...

Good luck!